# Ruby not loading CSV from stdlib

Tags: ruby

I'm not really sure why this isn't working and I am stuck finding a solution. Very simply, I am running a little script that does `require 'CSV'`, which has been working fine on my Mac with 1.9.3-p327, but has not been working from the server on p374.

The error I get is

> /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- CSV (LoadError)<br>
>   from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The case is important. `CSV` is not defined yet `csv` should be.

```
require 'csv'
```

I don't have a Mac at hand but it probably works because your FS (HSF+) is case insensitive whereas the server is sensitive.